# Remove records from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove records from a multidimensional array if certain criteria are met.  The condition is that the element 'cap' should only have 'Capped' or Uncapped', if 'Other' is there, it should be removed from the array.

I have tried using Unset() but with no luck.  It does not break the code, but it changes nothing.  Output of the array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Club Name
        [speed] => Annual Membership
        [cap] => Other
        [s_description] => Short description
        [l_description] => Long description
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 50\5Mbps Fibre with 250GB
        [speed] => Residential 50/5 Capped
        [cap] => Capped
        [s_description] => Short description
        [l_description] => Long description
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => FB-FP-B-V-50/5MBPS-400-24
        [speed] => Residential 50/5 Capped
        [cap] => Capped
        [s_description] => Short description
        [l_description] => Long description
    )
```

Code for removing the 'Other' record:

```
foreach ($product_details['cap'] as $key ->$val_test) {
    if ($val_test == "Other") {
        unset($product_details[$key]);
    }
}
```

I realise I may be doing something really stupid, but for something that should be fairly simple, it seems really difficult!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your main array is stored under the variable: $product_details

Your code would be

```
foreach($product_details as $key => $product){
    if($product['cap'] == "Other"){
        unset($product_details[$key]);
    }
}
```

You cant loop over '$product_details['cap']' as that is part of your inner array.
You must loop over your outer array then check the value of the inner array.

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT: On rereading of your question you could change your if statement to this to make it more open ended;

```
if($product['cap'] != "Capped" && $product['cap'] != "Uncapped"){
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Works like a chance.  WRT new IF statement, that was my plan.  Just wanted to get the Unset() working first

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
foreach ($your_array as $element) {
    if ($element['cap'] == "Other") {
        continue;
    } else {
        $newarray[] = $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question states that the asker wants to unset from the original array, not create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
```

Else you have to loop like above. There are other methods to map as well.